# Fast access to a (sorted) TList

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

My project (running on Delphi 6!) requires a list of memory allocations (TMemoryAllocation) which I store within an object that also holds the information about the size of the allocation (FSize) and if the allocation is in use or free (FUsed). I use this basically as a GarbageCollector and a way to keep my application of allocating/deallocating memory all the time (and there are plenty allocations/deallocations needed).

Whenever my project needs an allocation it looks up the list to find a free allocation that fits the required size. To achieve that I use a simple for loop:

```
for I := 0 to FAllocationList.Count - 1 do
begin
  if MemoryAllocation.FUsed and (MemoryAllocation.FSize = Size) then
...
```

The longer my application runs this list grows to several thousand items and it slows down considerably as I run it up very frequently (several times per second).

I am trying to find a way to accelerate this solution. I thought about sorting the TList by size of allocation. If I do that I should use some intelligent way of accessing the list for the particular size I need at every call. **Is there some easy way to do this?**

Another way I was thinking about was to have two TLists. One for the Unused and one of the Used allocations. That would mean though that I would have to Extract TList.Items from one list and add to the other all the time. And I would still need to use a for-loop to go through the (now) smaller list. **Would this be the right way?**

Other suggestions are **VERY** welcome as well!

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using FastMM?  From your description, it looks like FastMM does about the same.  I think FastMM actually uses several lists of Allocations for different sizes: a list for small (<32 bytes or something), medium (32-1024 bytes or so), and big (> 1024 bytes).

Comment: Have you considered using [FastMM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/)?

Comment: You need the GarbageCollector so is your application multithread?

Comment: FastMM would be a big step up from BorlandMM. On the down side it struggles under severe thread contention but that may not be an issue. First step though is to try FastMM.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about FastMM! I will try that out.    
@GJ: Yes, my application is multithreaded. It's not exactly a GarbageCollector, but only similar. I keep the memory allocations for reuse within my list. Only large memory allocation >1KiB are deallocated by the GC-function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several possibilities:

- Of course, use a proven Memory Manager as [FastMM4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/) or some [others](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/12/04/SynScaleMM) dedicated to better scale for multi-threaded applications;
- Reinvent the wheel.

If your application is very sensitive to memory allocation, perhaps some feedback about reinventing the wheel:

- Leverage your blocks size e.g. per 16 bytes multiples, then maintain one list per block size - so you can quickly reach the good block "family", and won't have to store each individual block size in memory (if it's own in the 32 bytes list, it is a 32 bytes blocks);
- If you need reallocation, try to guess the best increasing factor to reduce memory copy;
- Sort your blocks per size, then use [binary search](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Search/Binary_search#Delphi), which will be much faster than a plain for i := 0 to Count-1 loop;
- Maintain a block of deleted items in the list, in which to lookup when you need a new item (so you won't have to delete the item, just mark it as free - this will speed up a lot if the list is huge);
- Instead of using a list (which will have some speed issues when deleting or inserting sorted items with a huge number of items) use a linked list, for both items and freed items.

It's definitively not so simple, so you may want to look at some existing code before, or just rely on existing libraries. I think you don't have to code this memory allocation in your application, unless FastMM4 is not fast enough for you, which I'll doubt very much, because this is a great piece of code!